# Raspbian with kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10

Tags: raspbian

I'm looking for old version of Raspbian with kernel 2.6.18 ~ 3.10.10.

Answer (score 2):

Google points to http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/ which has old Raspberry Pi Foundation images.

You will have to work out which Linux kernels they use.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux (Branch: tab) suggests that 3.2.27 was the earliest kernel used.

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize a point made in joan's answer, a quick glance at [current "longterm" kernel releases](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html) shows that 3.2 dates back to at least January 2012 (I think the first 3.2 would be some months older), a month before first generation Pis became widely available, so it is very unlikely there is any branch of the Pi kernel predating that.

You are not strictly bound to using a specific kernel with a specific version of Raspbian, however, you will probably have to compile it yourself, install the modules properly, etc. and there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to raspbian version infos: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian